# How to simulate screen resolution realistically when testing responsive Web UI?

Tags: usability-testing, screen-resolution

I have tried to test our Web page in different resolutions with two different approaches:

- changing resolution on Web browser with [Resolution Test](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/resolution-test/idhfcdbheobinplaamokffboaccidbal) extension for Chrome
- simulating mobile devices with [Device Mode](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/device-mode/) in Chrome.

The page is rendered differently, depending on my approach. For instance, in device mode a page is zoomed out, e.g., font size seems to be adapted to the device resolution.

1. Why does it happen? Based on what information (headers, etc.) Web application decides to render layout differently?
2. Which approach is more realistic to evaluate layout for different resolutions on both mobile devices and standard laptop/desktop monitors?

Comment: You should also try settting different resolutions vis Control Panel/ Display when it comes to desktop views only.

Comment: @drabsv that would be 3rd approach. Why would it be better than the first two?

Comment: It is useful for checking which type of rendering shows the same with this method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are interested in testing for different screen sizes and features, I recommend to test with [Device mode of Chrome DevTools](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/device-mode/) which I think you are commenting in the question. You can set up your own devices or simply play with the Responsive device.

**There is nothing as close as testing in the real device**. For example, iOS Safari has a bug with [viewport units](https://github.com/rodneyrehm/viewport-units-buggyfill), that won't replicated with DevTools. To test iOS with higher fidelity I use the [Xcode Simulator](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/iOS_Simulator_Guide/Introduction/Introduction.html) which reproduces the bug.

---

Other resources:

[Material design - Resizer](http://material.io/resizer/)